"Return" a value if a specific Error occurs
I am creating n variables, and whenever an error occurs, I want to give a specific value to the variable.
Example:
a = "abc"
b = 0

def lastnext (word, count):
    last = word[count - 1]
    next = word[count + 1]
   
    return last,next


print(lastnext (a,b))

This way, whenever b = (len( a ) - 1) (in this case b = 2), the variable next would give me a IndexError, because there is no word[ 3 ]. Then, I want to "return" a specific value to the variable, like None .
I thought about using the try and except method to every single variable, but I guess it would be a whole different story with n variables.

Maybe use a loop?

What do you mean by "n variables"? Please show an example

@SIGHUP By “n variables” i mean a variable number of variables.

@SIGHUP Could you upload your answer again? I don't know why you deleted it, but i'd like to take a closer look to it. I remember that it also suited my question.

If you don't want to use exception handling then you could do this:
def lastnext(word, count):
    rv = ()
    for i in count - 1, count + 1:
        rv += (word[i],) if 0 <= i < len(word) else (None,)
    return rv


word = "ABCDE"

for count in range(len(word)):
    print(lastnext(word, count))

Output:
(None, 'B')
('A', 'C')
('B', 'D')
('C', 'E')
('D', None)


You can slice the word and use or for default value
def lastnext (word, count):
    return word[count-1:count] or None, word[count+1:count+2] or None

a = 'abc'
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(lastnext(a, i))

Output
(None, 'b')
('a', 'c')
('b', None)


Try this one:
a = "abcdef"
b = 0

def lastnext (word, count):
    if count-1<0:
        last = None
    else: 
        last = word[count - 1]
    try:
        next = word[count + 1]
    except IndexError:
        next = None
    return last,next

for b in range(len(a)):
    print(lastnext (a,b))

This gives the output:
(None, 'b')
('a', 'c')
('b', 'd')
('c', 'e')
('d', 'f')
('e', None)

So, whenever the index exceeds the limits of the string None is returned as a specific value.
Here two possibilities are used:

checking the count value for validity beforehand, and
performing the action and catching the error as it happens with try and except.


def lastnext (word, count):
    // convert word string to a map
    index_to_value_map = {}
    for i in range(len(word)):
        index_to_value_map[i] = word[i]

    // using map.get() to get value or an error string
    last = index_to_value_map.get(count - 1, "No last char")
    next = index_to_value_map.get(count + 1, "No next char")
   
    return last,next


Did you notice that comments are not written with // in Python?
